# React props states and Redux

Tags: reactjs, properties, components, state, redux

- What is the different between states and props?
- How can you pass a value of let's say `CompomentA` to `ComponentB` if we have have for example `ComponentA` which takes an input then `ComponentB` is suppose to output(to print it on the screen) that same value if we have a third component called `CompomentContainer` which is a container of both A and B?
- What is Redux? the definition of redux on the main website does not make sense to me. How does it work exactly? How is it useful to react?

Please bear with me, I hope my questions make sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are very valid questions. I've been there and I know how frustrating it is to read about redux and not understanding anything. For some reason people like to use fancy words, which sounds complicated but in reality things are very simple and easy.

**What is Redux?**
Redux is a Flux architecture. In simple words it will help you to manage the global state of your app.

**How does it work exactly?**
Redux will create a single "store", this store will have all the data that you need to render in your components, you can update the data using "actions", you will call the actions from your components, these actions will transfer the new data to the "reducers", inside of a reducer you will basically copy the data from the components to the global state (reducers should be pure functions).

**How is it useful to react?**
It's very useful! Mainly because you will be able to share data across components. Also by having a global state you could save it to the local storage (or a database) to add offline support.

**What is the different between states and props?**
You can define props to describe the properties that the component will receive when creating instances, you can think of props like parameters, for example:

`<MyComponent name="Crysfel" lastname="Villa" />`

The previous component is receiving two props, name and lastname. Props will allow you to send data from ComponentA to ComponentB, assuming ComponentB is a child of ComponentA. Props will also help you to receive data from redux. As a rule of thumb, you should never modify the value of the props, these values are just to receive data.

State on the other hand is an object that might contain configurations for your component, the idea is to handle the state of the component, for example a collapsible container, you could have a toggle property in the component's state and toggle the value when user clicks a button. However when using redux you will rarely use the component's state, because Redux is managing the state of your app.

For your second question about sending data between component, you would use redux for that, ComponentA should call an action and send the new data to the global state, then redux will update your component with the new data and then you can render the new data into ComponentB (using props).

Answer (score 0):

**What is the different between states and props?**

State is data that is tied directly to the React component in which it is set. Props is data that is passed into a child component from the parent component. Unlike state, props are immutable and never "set" directly.

**How can you pass a value of let's say CompomentA to ComponentB if we have have for example ComponentA which takes an input then ComponentB is suppose to output(to print it on the screen) that same value if we have a third component called CompomentContainer which is a container of both A and B?**

To pass value from Component A to ComponentB you would provide the value as `props`, passed in via the ComponentA render function. Something like this:

```
class ComponentA extends React.component {
  render() {
    return <ComponentB myvalue={value} />
  }
}
```

In ComponentB the value can be accessed: `this.props.myvalue`

**What is Redux? the definition of redux on the main website does not make sense to me. How does it work exactly? How is it useful to react?**

Redux is an implementation of the ideas of Flux with a few architectural differences. You can think of it as a library that helps you create a central data store that passes data one-way into React components. It allows you to maintain global state outside of the components themselves.

A top-level container component typically listens to the store and re-renders whenever the store data changes (see the `connect` function). The data is then passed from the container component into the children components that need that data so they can render properly.